# Getting empty dataFrame while merging based on matching column name, can anyone look into it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivAZ5.png)

I have two data frame and the column name is given in the attached image . I'm trying to filter out the matching records using pd.merge. Getting empty data frame as an output

```
    df1=self.wl_emp_merge
    df2=self.atw_list_df
    self.wl_atw_trader_match = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on="empName", right_on="Name")
    print(self.wl_atw_trader_match)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") This is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? I created a new df with only one column with the matching names.

```
import pandas as pd

col1 = "empName"
data1 = ['Erie', 'Bkah', 'Dlmoo']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({col1: data1})
col2 = "Name"
data2 = ['Erie', 'Bkah', 'Kach']
df2 = pd.DataFrame({col2: data2})

# create new df having column with only matching names
df_m = df1.merge(df2, left_on="empName", right_on="Name").drop(columns=['Name'])

print(df_m)
```

Output:

```
  empName
0    Erie
1    Bkah
```